# How to set alternate color for href background

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi i am want to make href link background alternate color how can i achieve this

```
<div class="left_column">
  <div class="category">
    <p>Category</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="side-link">
  <?php 
  $data=mysql_query("select categoryname from category");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($data))
  {
    ?>
    <li><a class="linkbutton" href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><?php echo $row['categoryname']; ?></a></li>
    <?php
  }
  ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: background-color: 000;?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="left_column">
                    <div class="category">
                        <p>Category</p>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="side-link">


        <?php 
        $data=mysql_query("select categoryname from category");
        $t =0;
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($data))
        {
            if($t==0){
                $t=1;
            ?>
            <li><a  class ="linkbutton odd" href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><?php echo $row['categoryname']; ?></a></li>
            <?php
            }else{
                     ?>
    <li><a  class ="linkbutton even" href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><?php echo $row['categoryname']; ?></a></li>
    <?php
             }

        }
        ?>
    </div>
```

in css for example:

```
enter code here

    .odd{
   background-color: red;
}
.even{
 background:green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check directly if the link is even or odd. However, you *can* check if the link is nested inside an element that is even or odd child of its parent:

```
.side-link li:nth-child(odd) .linkbutton {
    background-color: #F00;
}
.side-link li:nth-child(even) .linkbutton {
    background-color: #080;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to style alternative `li` elements

```
.side-link li{
    background:#ff0000;
}

.side-link li:nth-child(even){
    background:#878787;
}
```

if you want to style the `a` then you'd need to display block it to fill the space of the `li`